# DateTimePicker and PostgreSQL Data Table search

Tags: c#, postgresql, datetimepicker

I'm trying to search through DataGridView with DateTimePicker between two dates and I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it. Here is my code:

```
 private void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        if (comboBox1.Text == "Document Date")
        {
            CRUD.cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM archive WHERE docdate BETWEEN '" + dtpFrom.Text + "' AND '" + dtpTo.Text + "'", CRUD.con);
            NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.SelectCommand = CRUD.cmd;
            dt.Clear();
            da.Fill(dt);
            grid.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
```

My DateTimePicker has the following format when displayed on designer: 27.11.2020.
And format in postgreSQL table is 2020-11-27 as usual.
This is the error that I'm getting: **Npgsql.PostgresException: '22008: date/time field value out of range: "27.11.2020."'**
I'm aware that I have to change the format but not completely sure how to do it. Kind of a stupid question but I'm really new to PostgreSQL and C# so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: lear how to use SqlParameter: it will save you from this kind of headache for number and  date formatting and as a nice side effect will give a good protection against Sql Injection

Comment: That's a good advice, next on my TODO list, thank you. I'm writing this one for 3-4 PCs in a small company so I'm not afraid of Sql injection attacks particularly, that's why I haven't switched to parameters yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this query, This might work:

```
SELECT * FROM archive WHERE docdate::TIMESTAMP BETWEEN 
(split_part('27.11.2020', '.',2)||'/'||split_part('27.11.2020', '.',1)||'/'||split_part('27.11.2020', '.',3))::TIMESTAMP
--'" + dtpFrom.Text + "' 
AND 
(split_part('27.11.2020', '.',2)||'/'||split_part('27.11.2020', '.',1)||'/'||split_part('27.11.2020', '.',3))::TIMESTAMP
--'" + dtpTo.Text + "'
```

//Edited

COPY PASTE BELOW CODE:

```
private void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (comboBox1.Text == "Document Date")
        {
            CRUD.cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM archive WHERE docdate::TIMESTAMP BETWEEN (split_part('" + dtpFrom.Text + "', '.',2)||'/'||split_part('" + dtpFrom.Text + "', '.',1)||'/'||split_part('" + dtpFrom.Text + "', '.',3))::TIMESTAMP AND (split_part('" + dtpTo.Text + "', '.',2)||'/'||split_part('" + dtpTo.Text + "', '.',1)||'/'||split_part('" + dtpTo.Text + "', '.',3))::TIMESTAMP", CRUD.con);
            NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.SelectCommand = CRUD.cmd;
            dt.Clear();
            da.Fill(dt);
            grid.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I tried your solution and I got an error :"Npgsql.PostgresException: '42601: syntax error at end of input'" on da.Fill(dt); line.

Comment: Have you replaced that hardcoded date from my query with your fields?

Comment: Yes Sir I did, problem was in the split_part code, never used it before and I implemented it wrongly, I found the mistake and now everything is working just fine! Thank you very much! I have to move to sql parameters ASAP to decrease the margins for error in the code. I'm still a newbie sorry, you saved me here.

Comment: Cheers! Glad to help. :thumbsup: